# Computing distance in circle

Tags: circles, triangles

It seems to me as pretty simple, but I just can't get hold of it:

[image]

I am trying to compute `fn(x, r)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I changed the picture and now it should be clear how to solve the problem.